# Authorise mixed content <a href> tag?

Tags: iframe, https, cross-browser, content-security-policy

i have an issue with mixed-content (http/https) blocking.

I have three subdomains "a", "b" and "c". Only b is available over SSL.

I have a web application with the following frame structure:

- Navigate to http://a.example.com
- Page contains an iframe to another page on http://a.example.com
- iframe makes ajax request to https://b.example.com/
- iframe sets window.location.href to https://b.example.com/
- iframe (now on https://b.example.com/ ) loads nested iframe to another page on https://b.example.com/
- Nested iframe offers an `<a href="">` directly to http://c.example.com/

The last link is blocked by browser's mixed-content security policy:

Chrome 30: `[blocked] The page at https://b.example.com ran insecure content from http://c.example.com.`

Firefox 23: `Blocked loading mixed active content "http://c.example.com/"`

How can i authorise this direct `<a href="">` link to bypass mixed-content security policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first thought of making the `<a href="">` link point to https://b.example.com/ which would make a 302 redirect to the correct target on http://c.example.com/ , but i see Firefox are planning to block this as part of their mixed-content security strategy (bug [#418354](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418354) and [#456957](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=456957))

Other solutions would be to rearchitect all physical hardware to merge the b.example.com and c.example.com machines; or to attempt to make c.example.com available over SSL (messy, multiple vhosts and SNI is not yet sufficiently compatible)

A simple `target="_blank"` seems to avoid the problem and although it's not ideal, in my case it's suitable and i think i'll use this solution. I'll leave the question in case there are any other solutions.